Dynamic dependency for resource Reference using depends_on in terraform
I need to bind depends_on with multiple resource base on the condition.
I am using for_each as creating multiple resource for same type at resource level.
Now, I want to reference other resources using depends_on property  based on on the other property value like below e.g.
depends_on = each.value.backend_address_pool? [azurerm_lb.load_balancer, azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.pool_address] :[ azurerm_lb.load_balancer ]

but Terraform won't allow that, as it requires a static list. I've tried:

Checking dependent property null or not.
Using concat function to generate list.

How can I express this dependency?

Why do you need to create these resources in “pairs”? Can't Terraform first create all resources that you specify in depends_on and then all your „main” resources? I can't see any use case here.

Likely you don't have to express this dependency, which is lucky because the way that Terraform works ensures that depends_on values must be static (i.e. they must be fully known before any code is called and cannot be calculated dynamically). This is because Terraform requires that the dependency tree is fully understood before any computation is done.
However, depends_on is usually implicit. Presumably you're creating some change in the resource that refers to azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.pool_address if each.value.backend_address_pool is true, and presumably you're referencing azurerm_lb.load_balancer somewhere in the resource block either way. In this case -- GREAT! The implicit dependency tree is correct. No need to correct it.

@Aam Smith  there is another option, we can maintain separate resource, 1 having property with depends_on and another without it, but that is the duplication of code and i believe it's not a good practice. so finding other way
